# Problem with cloning columns columns with mutate() and strptime data

Tags: r, dplyr, strptime

I am currently at a point in my data preparation not getting anywhere.

I have two columns (from = "von", to = "bis") with a date in them. Unfortunately there are some observations, where the values are interchanged. I calculated the difference too ("tage_berechnet"), so you can see, that there is a mix-up because of the negative values.

I thought, I create two new columns and then check with IFELSE and depending on the difference being smaller or equal 0, I set the correct values.

Unfortunately the code always aborts. Do you have an idea?

This is an extract from the data. If you can't get a hint without existing data, I will provide a part of it as an update.

[image]

When I execute this code I get the errors, after that R Studio is hardly usable anymore :)

```
df_verletzungenResult <- df_verletzungenResult %>%
  mutate(von_neu = von) %>%
  mutate(bis_neu = bis) %>%
  mutate(von_neu = ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, bis, von)) %>%
  mutate(bis_neu = ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, von, bis))
```

ERROR:

```
Warnmeldungen:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `von_neu`.
ℹ Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
ℹ Input `von_neu` is `ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, bis, von)`. 
2: In ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `von_neu`.
ℹ Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
ℹ Input `von_neu` is `ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, bis, von)`. 
4: In ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
5: Problem with `mutate()` input `bis_neu`.
ℹ Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
ℹ Input `bis_neu` is `ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, von, bis)`. 
6: In ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
7: Problem with `mutate()` input `bis_neu`.
ℹ Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
ℹ Input `bis_neu` is `ifelse(tage_berechnet <= 0, von, bis)`. 
8: In ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
```

Could it be related to the fact that the format of the date is chosen clumsy? When creating the columns I have the following command:

```
df_verletzungenRaw$von <- strptime(df_verletzungenRaw$von,format="%d.%m.%Y")
df_verletzungenRaw$bis <- strptime(df_verletzungenRaw$bis,format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if_else` to maintain the date class and also you don't need multiple `mutate` statements.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(to - from),
         from_new = if_else(diff <= 0, to, from),
         to_new = if_else(diff <= 0, from, to))

df

#        from         to diff   from_new     to_new
#1 2021-09-06 2021-09-06    0 2021-09-06 2021-09-06
#2 2021-09-05 2021-09-04   -1 2021-09-04 2021-09-05
#3 2021-09-08 2021-09-05   -3 2021-09-05 2021-09-08
#4 2021-09-07 2021-09-08    1 2021-09-07 2021-09-08
#5 2021-09-04 2021-09-07    3 2021-09-04 2021-09-07
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(from = structure(c(18876, 18875, 18878, 18877, 
18874), class = "Date"), to = structure(c(18876, 18874, 18875, 
18878, 18877), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```